# SQL: Calculate distance between two points using coordinates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, coordinates, distance

I've got a table with lat and lng coordnates, and need to add the distance into a new column called 'distance' in Bigquery.

table

| start_lat | end_lat | start_lng | end_lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41.8964 | 41.9322 | -87.661 | -87.6586 |
| 41.9244 | 41.9306 | -87.7154 | -87.7238 |
| 41.903 | 41.8992 | -87.6975 | -87.6722 |

I haven't a clue how to do it. I saw some examples, but simply couldn't apply it into this case.
Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ST_DISTANCE function will calculate the distance (in meters) between 2 points.

```
with my_data as (
  select 1 as trip_id, 41.8964 as start_lat, 41.9322 as end_lat, -87.661 as  start_lng, -87.6586 as end_lng union all
  select 2, 41., 41.9306, -87.7154, -87.7238
)
select trip_id, 
  ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(start_lng, start_lat), ST_GEOGPOINT(end_lng, end_lat)) as distance_in_meters
from my_data
```

Output:

| trip_id | distance_in_meters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3985.735019583467 |
| 2 | 103480.52812005761 |

Comment: If this answers your question, then please consider marking the accept flag.